# pages_messaging not available for submission in Facebook App Review

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am creating a chatbot that requires pages_messaging permission.  But can't find such option in the App Review page.  Any idea?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Answering back to my own question.

It's not in the App Review.  It's in Product -> Messenger -> Setting.